# What is the size of Ready Queue in linux?

Tags: operating-system

Yesterday i understood in my Advanced Operating Systems class that there will be a limit in the number of processes that can be allowed to be placed in the Ready Queue.I would like to know that number for different operating systems.And also what happens when that number is exceeded? Meaning : what if more than that number of processes are created?

I tried to see what happens by running a small program which is

```
int main()
{
     while(1)
     system(fork());
     return 0;
}
```

The system immediately hung.Can anyone explain why my system hung?

Answer (score 2):

Some systems place no limit and will simply keep appending to a running queue as needed. There are options to restrict the maximum number of processes that a system can use but by default there are no restrictions (on some systems). On Linux you can change the ulimit which is processes per user and if you set it to something like 500 or less you will see that this program will not hang the system and will simply just run and use up CPU cycles from doing constant context switches.

By the way, what you're doing there is called a Fork Bomb and it is a small denial exploit used to cause a denial of service attack on a computer that does not have a limit on processes per user.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As per the Fork Bomb, how the operating system comes to know that it is under Form Bomb attack and denies the service? What happens to the memory when a Form Bomb is thrown?

Comment: There's not an easy way to check, usually what people do to prevent this is to place a limit on processes per user as stated above. Fork bomb will eventually consume all memory but the system hangs because it's simply just goin back and forth between do nothing processes that just keep spawning more processes so it spends more time in kernel mode handling this than in user mode so the system effectively hangs.